# Reload include on state change in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make an include refresh itself when the state changes in my app.

Example:

```
<div ng-include="'partials/search-form.html'"></div>
```

Global listener:

```
phonecatApp.run(function ($state,$rootScope, $log) {

    $rootScope.$state = $state;

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(){
        if( !$state.includes('search') ) {
            // refresh the search-form include in the header
        }
    });
});
```

How can I do this? Because as the form is outside of the ui-view and when I change the page it still has a value from the previous search query as it's still in the previous state... How can I refresh this so it's updated???

*Note: creating another ui-view isn't a solution as this form is just a simple include shown in a header across all pages and doesn't relate to any states, etc.*

Update: So you can see what I am doing with the form and controller:

```
phonecatControllers.controller('SearchCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $state, $location) {

    $scope.query = ($state.includes('search') ? $location.search()['q'] : '');
    $scope.filterQuery = ($state.includes('search') ? $location.search()['q'] : '');

    if(!$scope.query){
        $location.search('q', null);
    }
    $scope.queryChanged = function () {
        if($scope.query){
            $state.go('search', {'q': $scope.query} );
        } else {
            $location.search('q', null);
        }
        $scope.filterQuery = $scope.query;
    }
});

<form class="form-search" ng-controller="SearchCtrl" ng-submit="queryChanged()">
    <input name="q" ng-model="query" id="filter" type="text">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
</form>
```

---

**Update: The best idea I could come up with, would be to empty the input field like so:**

```
var q = document.getElementsByName('q');
q.setAttribute('value', '');
```

**When the state changes is NOT the search state. This automatically fires a change event on the input and then causes it to have it's ng-dirty class removed, etc.**

Comment: can't you reset the model?

Comment: @Th0rndike can you show an example? Remembering that this needs to be global.

Comment: What I mean is: if you have this form included in a page, that page probably has a model for the data shown in the form (even if it's included). Before changing pages reset the model, probably using statechange listener is not the best solution. Consider i'm making many assumptions as there's very little code in your question.

Comment: looks to me that the value you want to change is "$scope.query" and that you're executing "$scope.queryChanged" before changing pages. Then all you have to do is clear the query before executing the search inside the queryChanged function: **$scope.query = ''**

Comment: Can you show an example? That queryChangd function only fires on form submit and not page change. How would I target that $scope.query globally?

Comment: @Cameron see you need to post a fiddle/plunkr kinda stuff in action to get it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have at the moment:

```
phonecatApp.run(function ($state, $rootScope, $log, $location) {

    $rootScope.$state = $state;

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(){
        if( !$state.includes('search') ) {
            $('[name=q]').val('');
        } else {
            $('[name=q]').val($location.search()['q']);
        }
    });

});
```

I've had to use jQuery because Vanialla JS couldn't see the element. But it basically just sets the input value depending on where you are in the app.

The ONLY issue is that if you submit the form when it's empty it will then default back to what it was before! **Presumably because the model hasn't been reset!**

So if I do this instead:

```
$('[name=q]').val('').change();
```

It then triggers the model to be reset (from what I can tell) as it no longer submits the previous result... Thoughts? It feels dirty, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Since the form is available globally, my advice is that you put the query in the **$rootScope**. The rootscope is available on the entire application (if you inject it, of course), so you would be able to reset the value at any moment.

An even better solution would be to store the query value in the rootscope and access it using a service.

Comment: You don't need to change EVERYTHING to the rootScope, only the form value. The rest will be inside your controller's scope.

Comment: Could you show an example, as I don't understand how to pass the query to the rootScope and use it globally but also within the search controller. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For reloading the route you can use:

```
$route.reload();
```

But i'm not sure if that will reload the included file.

Perhaps you can set the string of the included file as a $scope variable and then set it as an empty string first and then put it back again? Not sure if it will work, probably needs a $timeout, $digest or $watch to make sure it is ready to flip.

Another option would be to set an

```
ng-if="someForm"
```

var to the first route and when you are done, set it to false and have another

```
ng-if="someOtherForm"
```

for the second include. Or use the same but set it to something falsy first.

But if it is about cleaning the form, there are other ways to do that. Like setting all model-vars to an empty string or null. So if you have it at $scope.searchEntry, you set it undefined or "".
In your example:

```
$scope.query = "";
```

Comment: Where would I set that `$scope.query = "";` so that the form would pick it up when I navigate somewhere that ISN'T the search page?

Comment: If you use a global controller you can post it there, otherwise you can use a $rootScope var for it.

Comment: Can you show me how I'd use the $rootScope var in my code? Thanks

Comment: As I don't understand how to populate the value of that input based on a rootScope rather than as is currently... Thanks